# using CCCC on Windows XP with Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, code-metrics

I am trying to use CCCC(C and C++ Code Counter) on a windows machine.I did not have Microsoft Visual C++ Toolkit 2003 but Visual Studio 2010 installed on my machine.
So,to get around the problem of creating the Windows installer on my box,I downloaded a Windows based installer from codeplex for CCCC.
Now,when I try to get the xml reports for the C++ files,they don't have anything in them.
I think I need to associate the correct compiler with CCCC.
There is very little help for using CCCC on Windows available over the net.
I believe this would be very trivial for someone who would have used CCCC on Windows.
Any thoughts anyone?
I am really hoping someone can guide me here.Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run CCCC on Windows:

1. `cd <root_directory_of_source_tree>`
2. run `dir /b /s | c:\cccc\cccc.exe -`
3. report is published:  `<root_directory_of_source_tree>\.cccc\cccc.xml`

I do not recall any special configuration I had to do for the Microsoft compiler.  Hope that helps.